# Error: OAuth2Credentials instance does not support refreshing the access token. How to create a AccessToken instance with token value string?

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-authentication, google-speech-api

I am working on streaming speech to text by using Google Speech to Text service on Android. [Here is official sample repository.](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/android-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/Speech) The sample runs successfully. But **Alternatively, you should get the access token on the server side, and supply client app with it.**

So I set up a server and create RESTful api for app to get the access token. 
`{"token":"1234567890sdertyuikjhgfghjk....."}`

And also use api: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token={token} to get the token info:

```
{
 "issued_to": "102073270616313859663",
 "audience": "102073270616313859663",
 "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
 "expires_in": 3600,
 "access_type": "offline"
}
```

Then create a AccessToken instance:
`AccessToken token = new AccessToken(tokenValue, expiresIn);`

But following error:

```
07-04 20:14:07.395 3023-3067/com.google.cloud.android.speech E/SpeechService: Error calling the API.
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNKNOWN
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:543)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$StreamObserverToCallListenerAdapter.onClose(ClientCalls.java:395)
    at io.grpc.ClientInterceptors$CheckedForwardingClientCall.start(ClientInterceptors.java:202)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.startCall(ClientCalls.java:276)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.asyncStreamingRequestCall(ClientCalls.java:266)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.asyncBidiStreamingCall(ClientCalls.java:106)
    at com.google.cloud.speech.v1.SpeechGrpc$SpeechStub.streamingRecognize(SpeechGrpc.java:217)
    at com.google.cloud.android.speech.SpeechService.startRecognizing(SpeechService.java:264)
    at com.google.cloud.android.speech.MainActivity$1.onVoiceStart(MainActivity.java:62)
    at com.google.cloud.android.speech.VoiceRecorder$ProcessVoice.run(VoiceRecorder.java:199)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: OAuth2Credentials instance does not support refreshing the access token. An instance with a new access token should be used, or a derived type that supports refreshing.
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.refreshAccessToken(OAuth2Credentials.java:208)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.refresh(OAuth2Credentials.java:175)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.getRequestMetadata(OAuth2Credentials.java:161)
    at com.google.cloud.android.speech.SpeechService$GoogleCredentialsInterceptor.getRequestMetadata(SpeechService.java:532)
    at com.google.cloud.android.speech.SpeechService$GoogleCredentialsInterceptor.access$900(SpeechService.java:450)
    at com.google.cloud.android.speech.SpeechService$GoogleCredentialsInterceptor$1.checkedStart(SpeechService.java:474)
    at io.grpc.ClientInterceptors$CheckedForwardingClientCall.start(ClientInterceptors.java:194)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.startCall(ClientCalls.java:276) 
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.asyncStreamingRequestCall(ClientCalls.java:266) 
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.asyncBidiStreamingCall(ClientCalls.java:106) 
    at com.google.cloud.speech.v1.SpeechGrpc$SpeechStub.streamingRecognize(SpeechGrpc.java:217) 
    at com.google.cloud.android.speech.SpeechService.startRecognizing(SpeechService.java:264) 
    at com.google.cloud.android.speech.MainActivity$1.onVoiceStart(MainActivity.java:62) 
    at com.google.cloud.android.speech.VoiceRecorder$ProcessVoice.run(VoiceRecorder.java:199) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

I could use the sample code:

```
 final InputStream stream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.credential);
 final GoogleCredentials credentials = 
 GoogleCredentials.fromStream(stream).createScoped(SCOPE);
 final AccessToken token = credentials.refreshAccessToken();
```

and get a **working Token**,  and get its token value by using `getTokenValue()` and get it expiration time by `getExpirationTime`. Then create a Token instance:
`AccessToken token = new AccessToken(tokenValue, expiresIn);` 
to return a AccessToken instance. But it will cause the same error.

So my question is that how to create an **working** AccessToken instance when I get the token value string and the expiration time.

Comment: Make sure that you're setting the valid timestamp for expirationTime parameter. If the timestamp is generated on the server-side, it should be generated with the proper time zone.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I still cannot create an working `AccessToken` via the constructor. But I use a socket server to solve the problem. Because the `AccessToken` has already implemented `Serializable` interface. So it's much easier to communicate it between client and server.

**Sever**

```
private void  runServer() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(port);

    Socket socket = ss.accept();
    ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

    final InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(credential.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    final GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(stream)
                    .createScoped(SCOPE);
    final AccessToken token = credentials.refreshAccessToken();
    os.writeObject(token);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issue, below solution worked for me:

```
String accessToken = "xxxx"; // Replace this with your access token
long timestampWhenTokenGeneratedInSecond = 1678956050; // Replace this with the timestamp when access token was generated
long tokenExpiresInSecond = 3599; // Replace this with your access token expiration time
long expirationTimeInMS = (timestampWhenTokenGeneratedInSecond + tokenExpiresInSecond) * 1000; // Convert it to milliseconds
Credentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.create(new AccessToken(accessToken, new Date(expirationTimeInMS)));
```

In `AccessToken` constructor, you need to pass an object of `java.util.Date` with token expiration timestamp in milliseconds.

---

Alternative (In case you don't know/have expiry time): You can use `new AccessToken(token, null)`.